# Chrome extension failure... whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a Chrome extension that parses a json page on a website with XHR so I can make a badge whenever a number changes on the page. I thought I had it, but when I add it to chrome, the icon appears but it wont do anything... What is the problem?

background.js: (edited)

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.create({'url': "http://www.bukkit.org/account/alerts"}, function(tab) {
  });
});
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( 'GET', 'http://www.bukkit.org/.json', true );
xhr.onload = function () {
    var unread = window.JSON.parse( xhr.responseText )._visitor_alertsUnread;
};
xhr.onerror = function () {
};
xhr.send();

if (unread>0){
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: unread});
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: "#FF0000"})
}
```

and my manifest.json:

```
{
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png"
   },
   "description": "Get Bukkit Alerts",
   "icons": {
      "128": "128.png",
      "16": "16.png",
      "48": "48.png"
   },

   "name": "BukkitAlert",
   "permissions": [ 
      "tabs", 
      "http://www.bukkit.org/*"
   ],
 "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },   "version": "1.0"
}
```

Thank you!
EDIT: Now the clicking on the icon to open a new tab works, but it says that the variable "unread" is undefined.

Comment: Inspect your `_generated_background_page.html` and the console will give you the corresponding error message if available.

Answer (score 1):

The color must be a string.

You wrote.

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: #FF0000})
```

Should be

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: "#FF0000"})
```

**Update**

Running this code shows that there is an error with the JSON format from the url.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.bukkit.org/.json', true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    var unread = window.JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)._visitor_alertsUnread;
    console.log( unread );
};
xhr.onerror = function () {
    console.log( "An error occurred" );
    console.dir(arguments);
};
xhr.send();
```

Always defined the `onerror` function, so that you can notify someone of a error with the server.

Comment: Okay, fixed one problem, but now there seems to be a problem with the first line. Any ideas?

Comment: The page I am parsing only displays correctly when you are logged in... Would that be an issue? @LarryBattle

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem. Contact the admins at the site and tell them to validate their JSON before they output it. JSON_encode should help them.